# Блокнот не сохраняет русские символы

Tags: unicode, ansi

Я делал текстовую заметку(.txt) в блокноте описывая Microsoft Macro Assembler, после этого блокнот взбунтовался. Он написал что в кодировке ANSI символы из юникода не уцелеют и я должен сохранить текст вдругом формате. Далее все текстовые файлы(.txt) стало невозможно редактировать, то что я трогаю превращается в строки вопросов. Как можно вернуть все назад? Перезагрузка не помогла[image: Вывод ошибки]

Comment: Здравствуйте. Проверьте установленную локаль в Windows в настройках языка в пункте "Языковые параметры" в панели управления.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ нашел в статье https://mb4.ru/text-editors/notepad/146-notepad-change-default-encoding.html. Спасибо за участие.